# How to convert SELECT TOP clause in SQL server to postgresql?

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, select

I have a procedure in SQL server that I need to migrate over to Postgresql.

the procedure has a select top clause as such:

```
select top 1 @conkeyId= Id from conkey where [Key] like @key
```

My pg procedure looks as follows:

```
create procedure updateCon(key varchar, value varchar)
language plpgsql
as $$
declare
@old_value_for_update varchar;
@conkeyIdbigint;



begin

select *
from conKey
where key like @key
limit 1

end; $$
```

there doesnt seem to be a postgresql equivalent of SELECT TOP so trying through the LIMIT keyword, but i'm a little stuck.

any idea?

conkey is a table laid out like so?

```
conkey
id bigint
key varcahr
```

Comment: Pretty good coverage here https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-limit/

Comment: Your pg procedure seems to have select statement in declaration. Move it to begin...end;

Comment: whoops, apologies must have pasted incorrectly. fixed :)

Comment: What is ` @conkeyId= Id` supposed to do the in SELECT part? Why are you comparing a variable with a column there (which results in a `boolean` expression)